# VB.NET For Each steps into loop body for an IEnumerable collection! How? Why?

Tags: vb.net, foreach

Warning: This is inherited legacy code that was initially put together in the early days of VB (not .net mind you). I have already dealt with all sorts of weirdness and evil bit this issue is weirder still.

I have a class that inherits from IEnumrable whose Count property is reporting 0 (zero) elements but the For Each loop steps into the loop body and tries to use the variable where it should just be moving on. My code:

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim d As Foo
    For Each d In fooCollection
        ' use d and throws an exception
    Next d
```

Weirder still, every time d is accessed i get an exception thrown in the output window:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.NullReferenceException'

but i'm not stopping on the exception (not in a try/catch block).

Is "On Error Resume Next" causing this weirdness?

***Weirdness found:***

Per Rowland's and JohnH's comments i checked the Foo class:
The GetEnumerator method inside of Foo didn't actually return anything! It had an empty body. That coupled with the On Error Resume Next before the loop caused the havoc! Wow this was ugly. Thanks for the clues guys!

Comment: Obvious question, does removing On Error Resume Next fix the problem?

Comment: How has `IEnumerable` been implemented on fooCollection? - it *may* be a bug in there?

Comment: @rowland: if you please to repost I can upvote you.

Comment: Dan's put roughly what I'd put, so I'd suggest passing the up-vote his way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the of the on error resume next.  Can you post what Foo looks like ?

Answer (score 3):

IEnumerable and Count aren't related.  When you do the `For Each` you're essentially doing this:

```
Dim en as IEnumerator = fooCollection.GetEnumerator()
While en.MoveNext()
   d = en.Current()
   ' your code here...
Wend
```

(Excuse my possibly-rubbish syntax; it's been a while since I've done VB.)

So, the value of your Count property has nothing to do with the functionality of the loop.  Have you implemented the IEnumerator yourself?  If so, I'd suspect you've done it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Behold the Evil of On Error Resume Next.  It resumes right into the loop when your fooCollection reference is Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an util method to clear points of all series of a chart, without remove series themselves:

```
' clear all serial of a chart
Public Sub clearChart(ByVal chart As Chart)
    Dim sc As SeriesCollection = chart.Series
    Dim etor As IEnumerator = sc.GetEnumerator()
    Dim serial As Series

    While etor.MoveNext()
        serial = etor.Current()
        serial.Points.Clear()
    End While
End Sub
```